# Canvas blinking cursor gets duplicated instead of moving forward onkeydown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

I am trying to make a blinking cursor move forward when I type text into a canvas. The cursor does move forward, but an old cursor remains blinking at the previous location for some reason.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './CanvasTextEditor.scss';

class CanvasTextEditor extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cursorPos: [40.5, 5.5],
      cursorSize: [1, 18],
      cursorColour: '#000000',
      cursorBlinkSpeed: 1,
      backgroundColour: '#FFFFFF',
      font: 'Arial',
      fontSize: 30,
      fontColour: '#000000',
      text: ''
    };
    this.cursorBlink = this.cursorBlink.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.c = document.getElementsByClassName('canvasTextEditor')[0];
    this.ctx = this.c.getContext('2d');
    this.ctx.font = this.state.fontSize + 'px ' + this.state.font;

    clearInterval(this.cursorBlinkFunc);
    this.cursorBlinkFunc = setInterval(this.cursorBlink, this.state.cursorBlinkSpeed * 1000);

    this.c.onkeydown = e => {
      console.log(e.key);
      clearInterval(this.cursorBlinkFunc);
      this.cursorBlinkFunc = setInterval(this.cursorBlink, this.state.cursorBlinkSpeed * 1000);

      switch (e.key) {
        case 'Enter':
          break;
        default:
          this.setState({cursorPos: [this.state.cursorPos[0] + this.state.fontSize, this.state.cursorPos[1]]});
          console.log(this.state.cursorPos);
      }

      this.setState({text: this.state.text + e.key});
      this.drawText();
    };
  }

  cursorBlink() {
    const x = this.state.cursorPos[0];
    const y = this.state.cursorPos[1];
    console.log('cursorBlink:', x, y);
    this.drawCursor(x, y);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.eraseCursor(x, y);
    }, this.state.cursorBlinkSpeed / 2 * 1000);
  }

  drawCursor(x, y) {
    this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
    this.ctx.lineTo(x, y + this.state.cursorSize[1]);
    this.ctx.lineWidth = this.state.cursorSize[0];
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.state.cursorColour;
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }

  eraseCursor(x, y) {
    this.ctx.lineTo(x, y + this.state.cursorSize[1]);
    this.ctx.strokeStyle = this.state.backgroundColour;
    this.ctx.stroke();
  }

  drawText() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.c.width, this.c.height);
    this.ctx.fillText(this.state.text, 20, this.state.fontSize);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <canvas className="canvasTextEditor" width="800" height="600" tabIndex="1"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CanvasTextEditor;
```

The positioning and some other stuff isn't correct yet, but I'd like to sort out the issue of the duplicate cursor first. Every time a key is pressed, a new cursor appears forward a bit from the previous one, and the previous one stays there blinking, almost as if it's taunting me. It's wacky!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I just forgot to do this.ctx.beginPath()

Oops